# Drupal 8 Metatag and Media Entity modules to set meta image tags

Tags: 8, media, meta-tags

On a Drupal 8 content type, I have a field with an entity reference field to a Media Entity field.  I would like to use the Metatag module to set the image that is on this Media entity in the og:image meta tag.

- Featured Image - `[node:field_im]` - Returns the entity name
- Featured Image type with delta 0 - `[node:field_im:0]` - Returns the entity name
- Media - `[node:field_im:0:entity]` - Returns the entity name
- Media ID - `[node:field_im:0:target_id]` - Returns the entity ID

In Drupal 7, the following token was available:

`[node:field-fimg:0:file:url]`

But I don't see anything like it in D8.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you'll need to do the following:

- Check on your modules page that the "Metatag: Open Graph" submodule
  is enabled.
- Go to metatag config page (Configuration > Search and
  metadata > Metatag).
- Add a new "default metatag" and select your
  content type in the "Type" selectbox.
- Fill in the rest of the fields similar like following picture (just don't forget to use your own field names:

[image]

Here are some things you need to know about my tokens:

- field_teaser_img: is the fieldname of my media entityreference on my
  content type.
- field_me_img: is the fieldname of my image field
  on my media entity type.
- facebook: is the imagestyle name I
  created for these metatags
- height, mimetype & width: are
  property fields of the media entity type yet I didn't create those
  fields but it does seem to work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Hatznie, while those options weren't in the Token browser, they do work.  My solution for the Media Entity Image bundle is as follows:

[node:field_im:entity:image]

Comment: I found that this solution pointed me in the right direction, but gave me a relative URL. This instead printed an absolute URL: 

[node:field_teaser_img:entity:field_me_img:entity:url]

(using your field name examples)

Answer (score 2):

From http://drupalsun.com/glassdimly/2017/08/23/drupal-8-how-get-image-style-tokens-metatags

```
[node:field_my_image_field:entity:field_image:my_image_style:url]
[node:field_my_image_field:entity:field_image:my_image_style:width]
[node:field_my_image_field:entity:field_image:my_image_style:height]
```

This worked very well for me, where `field_my_image_field` is my media-reference-field name