# Get token of image field in paragraph field

Tags: 8, tokens, paragraphs

We're implementing the Open Graph metatags so that social media shares can know which image to use as the "share" image on our pages. I'm having a problem figuring out the token for a image field URL in a paragraph field.

We have content types with a media field. The node listed under metatags "available tokens" `[node:field_media_card:entity:field_media_image]`. That by itself didn't work, but I was able to figure out (I don't quite remember how) that the `[node:field_media_card:entity:field_media_image:entity:url]` token gave the actual URL for the media image. From that point, I was able able to get `[node:field_media_card:entity:field_media_image:width]` and `[node:field_media_card:entity:field_media_image:height]`, which facebook also wants.

So that works for those content types with media fields.

However, for other content types, we have a paragraphs field with an image field in it. It's a custom paragraph with a custom field in it. Our paragraph is called "Jumbotron Hero" and the field in question is called "Background Image". I am having trouble creating a token to get the URL of its image.

The Available Token lists `[node:field_jumbotron_hero:entity:field_background_image]`. However I tried both `[node:field_jumbotron_hero:entity:field_background_image:url]` and 
`[node:field_jumbotron_hero:entity:field_background_image:entity:url]`, but neither set the `og:image` value. Along with the URL, I also want the height and width.

How can I figure out the token to get the url, height, and width of this field?

Comment: If the node image field is a media field then the one in the paragraph probably as well? Then you need a third `:entity` and the field name of the image file in front of `:url`.

Comment: @4k4 sorry I'm having a little trouble following you-- can you spell out exactly what you think the proper token might be, using placeholders (i.e. `yourfilefieldnamehere`) where necessary?

Comment: You didn't answer my question, but if the field `field_background_image` is a media field, then you need to append `:entity:field_media_image:entity:url`.

Comment: @4k4 Sorry I misunderstood. The field `field_background_image` is actually an image field.

Comment: this is very similar to https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/271750/25141
you probably need the `field_paragraph_name:entity` added into one of these tokens before the media-reference field